# Extract XML data using SSIS script componenet

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I am trying to extract xml data using script componenet(source), my xml contains multipe namespaces, hence I created a class with namespace remover method. But i get an error "illegal charecters in path" I am not sure, which part of the code is incorrect, would someone please provide me a soulution

```
{
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        /*
          Add rows by calling the AddRow method on the member variable named "<Output Name>Buffer".
          For example, call MyOutputBuffer.AddRow() if your output was named "MyOutput".
        */

        string filepath =@"D:\test\QuoteStop\StopQuoteResponseLog.1.xml";
        string fileContent = new StreamReader(filepath).ReadToEnd();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(fileContent);
       // MessageBox.Show(fileContent);
        NsRemove rm = new NsRemove();
        rm.stripDocumentNamespace(doc);
        XmlNodeList xnl = doc.GetElementsByTagName("OrderResponseLog");

        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnl)
        {

            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            if (xn["operationType"] != null) 
            {
                Output0Buffer.operationType = xn["operationType"].InnerText;
            }
            if (xn["quoteNumber"] != null) 
            {
                Output0Buffer.quoteNumber = xn["quoteNumber"].InnerText;
            }



        }

    }

}

public class NsRemove
{
    public XmlDocument stripDocumentNamespace(XmlDocument oldDom)
    {
        // Remove all xmlns:* instances from the passed XmlDocument
        // to simplify our xpath expressions.
        XmlDocument newDom = new XmlDocument();
        newDom.LoadXml(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
        oldDom.OuterXml, @"(xmlns:?[^=]*=[""][^""]*[""])", "",
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline)
        );
        return newDom;
    }
}
```

[image: sample xml]

Comment: Which line is the error occurring on?

Comment: @ChrisMack:i think its on this line "string fileContent = new StreamReader(filepath).ReadToEnd(), but I am not 100 percent sure, this code is inside script component and when I run the data flow task, i get a msgbox with error``illegal charecters in path``

Comment: I would try adding a `try`/`catch` block, as well as adding a breakpoint and debugging line by line. You could also try an `if (File.Exists(...` statement to see if that method finds the file.

Comment: Ok will try that thanks for your reply

Comment: @chris thanks Chris I was able to fix it , if file exists helped me